# Reverse all images and then start again instead of cycling in jQuery slider

Tags: jquery, slider

jQuery slider display all images up to end and then quick reverse goes to first image and then start again from first image. I want instead of showing all reverse images, display like cycling (do not show all reverse images). How to do it?

Wesite link: [designcompanyusa.com/test](http://www.designcompanyusa.com/test)

My code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.slider').jcarousel( {
        initCallback: slider_initCallback,
        scroll: 1,
        auto: 5,
        wrap: 'both',
        //This tells jCarousel NOT to autobuild prev/next buttons
        buttonNextHTML: null,
        buttonPrevHTML: null
    });
});

function slider_initCallback (carousel) {
    $('.slider-nav a').bind('click', function() {
        carousel.scroll($.jcarousel.intval($(this).text()));
        return false;
    });
}

function slider_firstInCallback(carousel, item, idx, state) {
    $('.slider-nav a').removeClass('active');
    $('.slider-nav a').eq(idx-1).addClass('active');
}
```